# How to Insert into another Database Server

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it possible to `INSERT` query to another db server?

> Current Db server: 192.168.59.2

**Example:**

```
Insert into 192.168.1.1.Testing.Student (id) values (1)
```

Comment: Are you doing this from a programming language? It should be able to open multiple connections to different servers.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to use MySQL [`The FEDERATED Storage Engine`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html). Per documentation

> The FEDERATED storage engine lets you access data from a remote MySQL
>   database without using replication or cluster technology. Querying a
>   local FEDERATED table automatically pulls the data from the remote
>   (federated) tables. No data is stored on the local tables.

It kind a similar concept like `Linked Server` in Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Simply Use Generate Script Feature of the SQL server :

[Follow Link](https://sqlserver-help.com/2013/12/13/did-you-know-you-can-generate-insert-statement-with-data-using-management-studio/)

Comment: Mysql is given in the tags. So SQL server will probably not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do something like that. Maybe you should look into [FEDERATED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-storage-engine.html) tables, where you can copy values to a table from one server to another.

You could have something like this on the table, which you're trying to map:

```
CREATE TABLE federated_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='mysql://user@your_host:3306/federated/test_table';
```

This [thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/create-a-trigger-to-update-table-data-on-another-servers-database) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the answers. I've answered my question by installing a trial version of navicat and export to excel then import to another db server. Thank you again guys!